# Are there any problems with using email addresses as IDs?

Tags: account

I am thinking of using an email address as a login ID for Sitecore (CMS).

In the settings

```
 <setting name="AccountNameValidation", value=".*">
```

, any character can be used.

We know that we can use an email address as the login ID.

Is there any problem when using an email address as login ID?

The version of Sitecore is 10.1.

I would appreciate your wisdom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OOTB Sitecore doesn’t allow email address formats to be stored in the username field but you can use an email address as a user-id for Sitecore login. As you mentioned the Sitecore setting `AccountNameValidation` sets a regular expression that gets used to validate whether a provided username has a valid format. You need to update it as an easy regex.

Second, you need to make sure that the email id you are using is unique for every user. When using the user's email address as a username, you should consider changing the membership provider in Sitecore to require a unique email. For this, you need to go to the `web.config` file and change the attribute `requiresUniqueEmail` to `true` -

```
 <add name="sql" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="security" applicationName="sitecore"
          minRequiredPasswordLength="1" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true"
          maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"/>
```

There is no problem using the email address as user id, but it's more an opinion-based question in terms of PROS and CONS, where some folks like it and some do not.

Comment: Thanks Mahendra.

Thanks for the tip about reflecting the settings in web.config to make the email address unique.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this with a Sitecore custom application. The technical details by Mahendra should work out well.

From the user perspective, make sure you have a way to let the users change their email address without affecting the username. People's email addresses change all the time due to changing last names, company etc and they need to be decoupled from the username.

Another approach is to randomize the username stored in Sitecore and change the login process to match on the email. This does introduce issues with debugging though. So, wouldn't recommend it.